# Is there something of type Multidimensional Bidirectional Multimap

Tags: c++, boost-bimap

Everything was going fine till I had one dimensional data, where I used `Bidirectional Multimap` like

```
typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::multiset_of<int>, bimaps::set_of<int>> bimap_one_d;
typedef bimap_one_d::value_type value_type;
bimap_one_d bimap;
```

My need is to store the date in multidimensional nature. Suppose I have many frames `1`, `2`, `3`, containing keys and values.

```
1 -> (100, 10), (70,50), (80, 30)
2 -> (50,60), (90,20), (100,40)
3 -> (210,200),(2345,16374), (98345,334)
```

How can I maintain `bidirectional multimap` like structure for the data where I have many rows (`1`, `2`, `3`) so that all frames are accessible like `bidirectional multimap`. For example, I should be able to go through any frame and access the key and value in `bi-direction`

**Note:** I am not interested to maintain three separate `bidirectional multimap`, one for each frame, indeed I am looking for a solution in a multidimensional nature, like we have `vector of vectors` or `multi dimensional array`.

Comment: It is not clear what you actually need but `std::array<bimap_one_d,N>` or `boost::bimap<bimaps::multiset_of<array<int,N>>, bimaps::set_of<array<int,N>>>` should come close, with the former being more multi-frame and the latter more multdimensional.

Comment: You can try out boost::multi index, you can do lot of things with it.

Comment: @stefaanv Thanks for your comment. In `Bidirectional multimap`, I can push only one frame say `1 -> (100, 10), (70,50), (80, 30)`, but I would like to push many frames. Just imagine it as multidimensional, where rows are different frames.

Comment: @Nik Thanks, will give a try.